# Ordenar imagens pela altura de cada uma

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

Tenho uma lista de imagens com dimensões diferentes. Queria que as imagens fossem ordenadas da menor para maior: a que tem `height` menor ficasse em primeiro e a de `height` maior ficasse por último. Utilizando apenas jQuery com HTML.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.sinfar.org.br/?q=listaConv3/1582" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/12082014164535.png" title="CASF" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.sinfar.org.br/?q=listaConv3/1582" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/12082014164559.png" title="SINFAR" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://paf.crfsp.org.br/paf/?cb/benef/Cursos_de_Graduacao_Especializacao_e_Pos-graduacao/841106593608856" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/12082014164626.png" title="PAF" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.unifran.edu.br/site/home/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/12082014164654.jpg" title="UNIFRAN" /></a>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.ibramrp.com.br/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014151738.png" title="Instituto Brasileiro de Acumpuntura" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.anfarmag.org.br/home" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014151823.jpg" title="Anfarmag" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.multigene.net.br/portal/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014151856.jpg" title="Multigene" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.faa.edu.br/institucional.php" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152017.png" title="CESVA" /></a>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.sindicatonutricionistas.com.br/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152048.jpg" title="SINDICATO DE NUTRIÇÃO" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.abfh.org.br/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152123.png" title="ABFH" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.lipochemicals.com/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152212.PNG" title="lipo chemicals" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.belezain.com.br/index.php" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152252.png" title="BELEZAIN" /></a>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.esteticainfoco.org/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152325.png" title="estetica in foco" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/belezainfocotv" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152420.png" title="beleza in foco tv" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://medicatriz.com.br/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152459.jpg" title="medicatriz" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.idealterapia.com.br/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152539.jpg" title="idealterapia" /></a>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.congressoconsulfarma.com/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152703.png" title="congresso consulfarma" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.consulfarma.com/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152730.png" title="consulfarma" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.unicamp.br/unicamp/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152803.png" title="unicamp" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.grupoinvestiga.com.br/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152856.png" title="Grupo Investiga" /></a>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
        <a href="http://www.allergisa.com.br/" target="_blank">
            <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/26082014152924.png" title="Allergisa" /></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Para gerar o código HTML utilizo Web Forms:

```
<%
 var parceiros = bdParceiros.ListarTodos();
 int i = 1;

 foreach (var parceiro in parceiros)
 { 
 %>

            <%if(i==1){ %>
            <div class="row">
                <%} %>
                <div class="col-lg-3  parceiros ">
                    <a href="<%=parceiro.Link %>" target="_blank">
                        <img class="well" style="background: none" src="http://ipupo.com.br/arquivos/Parceiro/<%=parceiro.Logo %>" title="<%=parceiro.Nome %>" /></a>
                </div>
                <%if(i==4){
                      i=0;%>
            </div>
            <%}
                  i++; %>
            <%} %>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttma4qxo/1/)

Comment: Ok, mas seu problema não é no HTML. Poste o código que não consegue ordenar as imagens.

Comment: @user6492, eu nem sei como começar, não sei se é possível.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aqui fica uma ideia, possivelmente daria para comprimir o código, mas é prático assim para ser perceptivel:

```
// colocar as imagens em cache
var imagens = $('img').get();
var row = $('.row');

// criar uma array de objetos, com a altura e o elemento que envolve cada imagem
var alturas = imagens.map(function (el) {
    var altura = el.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    return {
        altura: altura,
        elemento: $(el).closest('.col-lg-3')
    };
});

// arrumar a array de objetos por alturas
alturas = alturas.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.altura - b.altura;
});

// apagar o conteudo original (atênção a possiveis event handlers)
row.html('');

// restaurar o conteudo, agora na ordem certa
$(alturas).each(function () {
    console.log(this.altura); // só para verificação
    $('.row').append(this.elemento);
});
```

Como o @bfavaretto indicou, nos comentários em baixo, lembre-se que este código deve correr somente depois de as imagens estarem carregadas, senão o cálculo de alturas não vai funcionar.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/mkm25zb4/

Comment: Só precisa garantir que isso rode após o carregamento de todas as imagens (por exemplo, no window.onload).

Comment: Só não entendi porque adicionou várias vezes as mesmas imagens.

Comment: @bfavaretto boa observação- Juntei esse detalhe.

Comment: @Sergio, no HTML existem 21 imagens, depois de rodar seu código ele replica, vira mais de 60. As imagens aparecem umas 3 vezes cada.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo, é assim que quer? http://jsfiddle.net/mkm25zb4/1/ - cada `.row` com as imagens ordenadas dentro de si?

Comment: @Sergio, na realidade é ter uma ordenação das imagens, igual sua resposta. Então para que o bootstrap não perca o alinhamento, é necessário que a cada 4 imagens esteja contida em uma linha.

Comment: @Sergio, mas acredito que não caiba nesta pergunta. Consegue ajustar aqui. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Você tem à disposição, via JQuery, a função `sort()`. Uma possível solução seria a seguinte:

```
$lista = $('div.row div.parceiros').sort(function (itm1, itm2) { 
    return $('.well',itm1).height() > $('.well',itm2).height();
});
```

Após a ordenação, você pode modificar a lista original:

```
$('div.row').append($lista);
```

[Veja aqui o exemplo no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/42d9ekb6/)

Comment: Bem visto, eu usei o `.sort()` nativo do javascript, você usou o do jQuery, que permite de facto re-posicionar os elementos. `+1`

Comment: @Sergio obrigado - de qualquer maneira, é sempre interessante saber como libraries como o JQuery manipulam elementos DOM. Neste caso, o seu post é mais completo.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
var alturas = new Array();

var _height = 0;

$(".parceiros img").each(
    function () {
        alturas[$(this).height()] = $(this).height();
    }
);

alturas.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b
});

var _height = 0;
var print = "";
var j = 0;
$.each(alturas, function (index, value) {
    $(".parceiros").each(
        function () {
            if ($("img", this).height() == value) {
                if (j % 4 == 0) {
                    print += "<div class='row'>";
                }
                print += $(this)[0].outerHTML;
                if (j % 4 == 0) {
                    print += "</div>";
                }
                j++;
            }
        });
});

$("body").html(print);
});
```

Isso é uma possível solução.